# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?' in upgrading smart contract using @openzeppelin/hardhat-upgrades

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, hardhat, openzeppelin

I am trying to deploy an upgradable smart contract on polygon Mumbai tesnet. I am getting this error

```
smart-contract/node_modules/@openzeppelin/hardhat-upgrades/dist/index.js:108
        compiler.settings ?? (compiler.settings = {});
                           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (/Users/jagdish/workspace/speedrun-simple-nft-example/smart-contract/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1587:43)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jagdish/workspace/speedrun-simple-nft-example/smart-contract/hardhat.config.ts:4:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
```

while trying to run the deploy script.

here are my configs and deploy scripts:

hardhart.config.ts

```
import { task } from "hardhat/config";
// import "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle";
import 'hardhat-watcher';
import '@openzeppelin/hardhat-upgrades';
import '@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers';
import dotenv from "dotenv"
dotenv.config()


// This is a sample Hardhat task. To learn how to create your own go to
// https://hardhat.org/guides/create-task.html
task("accounts", "Prints the list of accounts", async (taskArgs, hre) => {
  const accounts = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

  for (const account of accounts) {
    console.log(account.address);
  }
});

// You need to export an object to set up your config
// Go to https://hardhat.org/config/ to learn more

/**
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.4",
  watcher: {
    compilation: {
      tasks: ['compile'],
    },
    node: {
      tasks: ['node'],
    },
  },
  networks: {
    matic: {
      url: "https://polygon-rpc.com/",
      accounts: [process.env.ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY]
    },
    matic_mumbai: {
      url: "https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com",
      accounts: [process.env.ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY]
    }
  }
};
```

deploy.ts

```
import { ethers, upgrades } from "hardhat";

async function main() {
  const contract = await ethers.getContractFactory("YourCollectible");
  console.log("Deploying Contract ...");
  const c = await upgrades.deployProxy(contract, { constructorArgs: ["Your Collectables", "YCB"] })
  // const c = await contract.deploy("Your Collectable", "YCB");

  await c.deployed();

  console.log("Contract deployed to:", c.address);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "smart-contract",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "run": "hardhat compile",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.0.6",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.3",
    "@openzeppelin/hardhat-upgrades": "^1.20.0",
    "@typechain/hardhat": "^6.1.2",
    "chai": "^4.3.6",
    "ethereum-waffle": "^3.4.4",
    "ethers": "^5.6.9",
    "hardhat": "^2.9.9",
    "hardhat-watcher": "^2.3.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.8.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.7.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1"
  }
}
```

I am not sure whether it is the node version issue in my local or do I have to downgrade the @openzeppelin/hardhat-upgrades version (I have tried that).
Node version: v12.22.10
Can anyone help on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with node 12. Problem solved after updating to node 16 and running yarn again.